# Benchmark using floating point math

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, numpy

I wrote some code in Python, to benchmark mathematical operations. It does not do anything in particular besides just calculating a lot of floating point numbers.

**To clarify:** I need 128-bits precision floating point numbers.

```
from __future__ import division
from numpy import arctan, sin, absolute, log10
from mpmath import *
import time
imax = 1000001
x = mpf(0)
y = mpf(0)
z = mpf(0)
t = mpf(0)
u = mpf(0)
i = 1
mp.prec = 128
start_time = time.time()
while i < 1000001:
    i += 1
    x = mpf(x + 1)
    y = mpf(y + x * x)
    z = mpf(z + sin(y))
    t = mpf(t + absolute(z))
    u = mpf(u + log10(t))

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print x
print y
print z
print t
print u
```

This took approximately 87 secs to print results. How can I improve this code? My friend in [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) wrote similar program and it took only 3.14 secs for him to  print results in 128-bit precision.

Also in general I want to improve speed of my code. Instead 87 secs I want to reach times much closer to [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I maintain the [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) library which also provides arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

`gmpy2` includes fast integer arithmetic based on the GMP library. If `gmpy2` is not installed, `mpmath` uses Python's native integer type(s) for computation. If `gmpy2` is installed, `mpmath` uses the faster `gmpy2.mpz` integer type. You didn't mention if you have `gmpy2` (or `gmpy`, an older version) installed, so I ran one test with your original code, `mpmath`, and without `gmpy2`. The running time was ~91 seconds. With `gmpy2` installed, the running time was ~63 seconds.

The rest of the examples assume `gmpy2` is installed.

Your code include superfluous calls to `mpf()`. Since `x` is already an `mpf`, the result of `x+1` will also be an `mpf` so the `mpf()` call is not needed. If I remove those calls, the running time drops to ~56 seconds.

You import from both `numpy` and `mpmath`. `mpmath.sin` and `mpmath.log10` replace the functions imported from `numpy`. But you are still using `numpy.absolute`. Numpy can be very fast but only when uses types it natively supports. If I remove `numpy` and change `absolute` to `abs`, the running time drops to ~48 seconds.

Here is the code with all the changes listed from above:

```
from __future__ import division
from mpmath import *
import time
imax = 1000001
x = mpf(0)
y = mpf(0)
z = mpf(0)
t = mpf(0)
u = mpf(0)
i = 1
mp.prec = 128
start_time = time.time()
while i < 1000001:
    i += 1
    x = x + 1
    y = y + x * x
    z = z + sin(y)
    t = t + abs(z)
    u = u + log10(t)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print x
print y
print z
print t
print u
```

I don't see any other significant improvements for an `mpmath` based approach.

`gmpy2` also provides arbitrary-precision floating point based on the MPFR library. If I use `gmpy2` instead, the running time is reduced to ~18 seconds.

Here is the code for a `gmpy2` based solution:

```
from __future__ import division
import gmpy2
from gmpy2 import mpfr, sin, log10
import time
imax = 1000001
x = mpfr(0)
y = mpfr(0)
z = mpfr(0)
t = mpfr(0)
u = mpfr(0)
i = 1
gmpy2.get_context().precision = 128
start_time = time.time()
while i < 1000001:
    i += 1
    x = x + 1
    y = y + x * x
    z = z + sin(y)
    t = t + abs(z)
    u = u + log10(t)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print x
print y
print z
print t
print u
```